# Laravel - Search Facility on site using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm a laravel newbie!!! And struggling to find out how to create a search and return the results.

Here's all my code on gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8289692

I've put everything in the gist from the form to the route, the controller and the model!

```
/* Route */
Route::get('/search/{q}', 'HomeController@search');


/* Form from web page */
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/search/" method="post">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Programmes" name="1">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
</span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>


/* Controller */
public function search($q)
{
$q = Input::get('term');
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
$query = DB::tables('wc_program');

foreach($searchTerms as $term)
{
$query->where('JobRef', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
}
$results = $query->get();
}


/* Model (just in case) */
class Search extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'wc_program';
public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code

Comment: You should put the code here, not on an external resource (c'mon, it's 40 lines of code). Anyway, what's the problem? Help in what? Is not working? What is it supposed to do / what it does instead?

Comment: It returns the following the error:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Are you using your own namespaces?  If so make sure you adjust the route accordingly, e.g. http://laravel.com/docs/controllers.  You should also try making the parameter optional, since that won't be present in the URL until you user submits through the form.  Route::get('/search/{q?}', 'HomeController@search');

Comment: Not using own namespaces, no, so i guess it was the route casuing the probem based on the error message so i'll try your route suggestion @Dave

Comment: Which i may add also didnt work same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **some issues** in your code:

---

Your form is using `POST` method, but your route is a GET route. And this accounts for the `NotFoundHttpException`. So make your route like:

```
Route::post('search', 'HomeController@search');
```

There's no need for a parameter, since your catching it with POST anyway, not GET!

---

Your input doesn't have the name 'term', but '1'. That might be a typo, but anyway, make it so:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Programmes" name="term">
```

Also, I suggest using Laravel's URL methods to build a correct url:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="{{URL::to('search')}}" method="post">
```

Or better:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'search', 'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-left', 'role' => 'search')}}
```

---

Now, to the controller. Let's rewrite to suite the new route:

```
public function search()  //no parameter now
{
  $q = Input::get('term');
  if($q && $q != ''){
    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
    $query = DB::table('wc_program');  // it's DB::table(), not DB::tables

    if(!empty($searchTerms)){

      foreach($searchTerms as $term) {
        $query->where('JobRef', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
      }
    }
    $results = $query->get();

    dd($results); // for debugging purpose. Use a View here
   }
}
```

Comment: Next question would be now its working thanks to you, how can i paginate it?