# Paginate search result laravel

Tags: laravel-4

After some help in a previous post [Laravel - Search Facility on site using Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959124/laravel-search-facility-on-site-using-eloquent/20960410#20960410) I now need to some help on paginating the result using the built in laravel pagination class.

```
public function search()  //no parameter now
{
 $q = Input::get('term');
 if($q && $q != ''){
  $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
  $query = DB::table('wc_program');  // it's DB::table(), not DB::tables

if(!empty($searchTerms)){

  foreach($searchTerms as $term) {
    $query->where('JobRef', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
  }
}
$results = $query->get();

dd($results); // for debugging purpose. Use a View here
 }
}
```

Comment: I changed $results = $query->get();
to

$results = $query->paginate(10);

Which paginates but when I go to page 2 page 3 etc etc I get 

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Is this something to do with routing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `get` to `paginate` and provide number of items per page.

```
$results = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Which is what i have done but error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException Is this something to do with routing ?


My route is: Route::post('search', 'HomeController@search');

Comment: When you click on the link which takes you to 2nd (or any other page), you no longer do `POST` request but `GET` request instead. This is why `Route::post(...)` does not work. Simply change search form method to `GET` and register route like this `Route::get('search', 'HomeController@search');` and you are good to go.

Comment: Ok and how can i change the method from post to get in this

{{Form::open(array('url' => 'search', 'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-left', 'role' => 'search'))}}

Comment: `{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'search', 'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-left', 'role' => 'search', 'method' => 'get')) }}`

Comment: Yes that worked, but now another problem:
When i got to localhost/search?page=2 I get a json of user logged in

Comment: This leads to another problem/question. Open another question and post whole code - controller method and/or view file. Cannot help you without that. Since you say the answer helped you, could you please accept/upvote, please.

Comment: Can we move to a chat save me posting another question?

Comment: full controller code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8291479 and ive moved this to a chat if you can spare 5 mins to help me

Comment: Next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961006/paginate-search-laravel-issue