# Paginate / Search Laravel issue

Tags: laravel-4

After a couple of conversations on here i'm finally getting somewhere but after the pagintion now works when i got to search?page=2 i get a json array of the logged in user and not page 2 of the results.

Here's my controller:

```
  public function search() 
  {
  $q = Input::get('term');
  if($q && $q != ''){
    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
    $query = DB::table('wc_program');

    if(!empty($searchTerms)){

      foreach($searchTerms as $term) {
        $query->where('JobRef', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
        $query->orwhere('Road', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
      }
    }
    $results = $query->paginate(10);


    return View::make('layouts.results', compact('results'));
   }
}
```

Route:
         Route::get('/search', 'HomeController@search');

So how can i work around this?

Comment: Post browser URL (to verify URL is catched by Laravel) and View file if possible.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/search?page=2 is url

View-  because its a but long is here > https://gist.github.com/lstables/8291815

Comment: I see no problem here. Where is JSON string printed? Before view is rendered or is it a part of rendered view?

Comment: When i got to localhost:8000/search?page=2 i get 

{"id":1,"email":"me@gmail.com","permissions":"{\"user.create\":-1,\"user.delete\":-1,\"user.view\":1,\"user.update\":1}","activated":1,"activation_code":"VXC35tefg","activated_at":"2014-01-03 13:42:04","last_login":"2014-01-04 12:36:40","persist_code":"$2y$10$SsdcSuohrbGpAKTbAPJ7WOg05qU81IWI1VeWsJHvzb8YBX0adFUtW","reset_password_code":null,"first_name":"Test","last_name":"Test","created_at":"2014-01-03 13:37:50","updated_at":"2014-01-04 13:44:46","username":"test"}

Comment: There must be something other involved, post content of `routes.php`

Comment: With pleasure, again a little too long to put on here so over at gists again https://gist.github.com/lstables/8292022 that is my full routes file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44658/discussion-between-andreyco-and-the-unforgiven-ii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append query string to the pagination.

in your controller, pass the query string to the view.

```
return View::make('layouts.results', compact('results', 'q'));
```

**In your view (results.blade.php):**

append the query string to the pagination otherwise in page 2 you will not get any result.

```
<?php echo $results->appends(array('term' => $q))->links(); ?>
```